# many to many relation performance

Tags: mysql, performance, many-to-many

I have three tables. My news have on or several categories.

```
News
-------------------------
| id   |  title |  created


Category
-------------------------
| id   |  title


News_Category
-------------------------
| news_id | category_id
```

But i have many rows on News about 10,000,000 rows. Using joind for fetch data will be performance issue.

```
Select title from News_Category left join News on (News_Category.news_id = News.id)
group by News_Category.id order by News.created desc limit 10
```

I want to have best query for this issue. For many to many relation data in huge tables which query have better performance.

Please give me the best query for this use case.

Comment: There's a MySQL doc page about [`LIMIT` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html). I'd recommend taking a look at that. Also try using `SELECT DISTINCT News_Category.id, title FROM News_Category...` instead of the `GROUP BY` to get distinct values. I'm not sure if it will speed things up but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The best performance for that query, is given by permanently store it. This is you need a materialized view.

On MySQL you can implement the materialized view by create a table.

this is

```
create table FooMaterializedView as
(select foo1.*, foo2.* from foo1 join foo2 on ( ... ) where ... order by ...);
```

and now **depending on how often the source tables change (this is receive inserts, updates or deletes) and how much you need to use the latest version of the query you need to implement suitable view maintenance strategy**.

This is, depending of your needs and the problem itself perform:

1. full computation (i.e. truncate the materialized view and generate it again from scratch) might be enough
2. incremental computation. If it is too costly to the system perform a full computation very often, you must capture **only** the changes on the source tables and update the materialized view according to the changes.

---

If you need to take the incremental approach, I can only wish you the best luck. I can point you that you can use triggers to **capture the changes on the source tables**, and you will need to either use an algorithmic or an equalization approach to **compute the changes** to make to the materialized view.